# ColorBox - add ALT text to gallery images?

Tags: jquery, accessibility, colorbox

Is there any way to make ColorBox place ALT text on the IMG tags it generates?  Note that I am NOT looking for a caption, but for a text alternative that screen readers can recognize and read aloud.

A basic [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) gallery looks something like this:

```
<p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
<p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
<p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
```

And then it's initialized with JS like this:

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
```

The TITLE attribute of the A element gets used as a descriptive caption.

But IMG elements in generated HTML lack an ALT attribute.  Here's a sample:

```
<img
    src="/_files/images/photos/primo-tour/tour1.png"
    id="cboxPhoto"
    style="border: medium none; display: block; float: none; cursor: pointer; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
/>
```

Because it lacks an ALT attribute, screen readers like JAWS and NVDA read the SRC attribute aloud, which is annoying for blind users.  It also means that if you have an image full of text that needs to be repeated as actual text for blind listeners, the caption gets too big for the available space.  Thus:

[image: A colorbox with an over-long caption.]

Note the long caption at the bottom which redundantly repeats the text that's baked into the image.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy all title attributes to alt attributes at startup: (attempting to clone anchor properties seems not to work)

```js
$(function(){
    $('a.group1').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('alt', this.title?this.title:'');
    });
    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
});
```

Then colorbox copies the alt attribute to image tag automatically.

[testing fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/snteA/)

Comment: True, but copying the ALT attribute to the A element doesn't help -- Colorbox doesn't know to copy it into the IMG it creates when someone opens the gallery.

Comment: Will, just tested it on localhost and colorbox copied the alt attribute from anchor to img tag. So it seems to work ok even without a hack.

Comment: The alt attribute is only a valid attribute for images, not any tag such as the anchor.

Comment: @RyanB Yes you're right, semantically it's designed for images, although practically can be used anywhere. But if you check the page you can see, if this library finds it, then copies it from a to img tag.

Comment: @Stano "Practically can be used anywhere." Yeah nothing is stopping you from doing `<a href="......" alt="...">`. Is it valid? No. Is it semantically correct? No, unless you can link to a W3C source stating it is. Will *any* assistive technology pay attention to it? ***NO!***

Comment: @RyanB Well it's a good to hear that this attribute is ignored by any assistive technology. Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: Now if you were able to add a `data-*` (http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), such as `data-alt` to the anchor, add that to the image then strip the data- part off, that would be ok.

Comment: Oh yeah i know that J.R.'s page, have seen it recommended multiple times in answers here on stackoverflow already. Dude you're right, i also like valid and readable pages of course, just i think one non-standardized attribute (for the helpful purpose only) is tolerable. That's all.

Comment: It seems that colorbox DOES copy ALT text from the calling element if that attribute is present (even though that's invalid usage). But my institution is using Colorbox 1.3.15 (from 2010) when the alt-copying bit wasn't added until 1.4.11 in 2013.  I'm accepting the answer since it will *work* for newer versions, despite the annoying non-semantic approach. Until we upgrade, I'm using the colorbox onComplete callback to read alt text from a DATA-ALT attribute on the anchor, which gets the job done and follows standards.

Comment: True, it's [much better and cleaner solution to use the onComplete callback](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/snteA/3/). Thanks Will and Ryan and have a good time.

Answer (score 2):

The author of the Colorbox library provided this answer [in March 2015 on Github](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/700#issuecomment-76991055):

> You can now do something like the following:
>
> ```
> <a class="example" href="example.jpg" data-cbox-img-attrs='{"title": "Hello", "alt"="Goodbye"}'>Grouped Photo 3</a>
> ```
>
> The `data-cbox-img-attrs` attribute takes in a JSON object of attribute/value pairs you want on the `<img>` element. However, you can redefine how this works by changing Colorbox's createImg property. The reason I went with the JSON object is because I didn't want to hard-code in which attributes should be checked for.
>
> But if you dislike using the JSON object you could redefine `createImg` to offer a different means of setting the img attributes. For example:
>
> ```
> $.colorbox.settings.createImg = function(){
>     var img = new Image();
>     var alt = $(this).attr('data-alt');
>     var title = $(this).attr('data-title');
>
>     if (alt) {
>         img.alt = alt;
>     }
>     if (title) {
>         img.title = title;
>     }
>     return img;
> };
> ```

I've tested both with success on version 1.6.1.